# How to show Feature Names in Graphviz?

Tags: pandas, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, graphviz, decision-tree

I'm building a tree in Graphviz and I can't seem to be able to get the feature names to show up, I have defined a list with the feature names like so:

```
names = list(df.columns.values)
```

Which prints:

```
    ['Gender',
 'SuperStrength',
 'Mask',
 'Cape',
 'Tie',
 'Bald',
 'Pointy Ears',
 'Smokes']
```

So the list is being created, later I build the tree like so:

```
 export_graphviz(tree, out_file=ddata, filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=False, impurity=False, feature_names=names)
```

But the final image still has the feature names listed like X[]:
[image]

How can I get the actual feature names to show up? (Cape instead of X[3], etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only imagine this has to do with passing the names as an array of the values. It works fine if you pass the columns directly:

```
export_graphviz(tree, out_file=ddata, filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=False, impurity=False, feature_names=df.columns)
```

If needed, you can also slice the columns:

```
export_graphviz(tree, out_file=ddata, filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=False, impurity=False, feature_names=df.columns[5:])
```